# What are alternative ways of saying "pressing the keyboard"?

Tags: phrase-requests, synonyms

I am looking for alternative ways of saying "pressing the keyboard" to include in a slogan. So I want a short and sweet phrase.

I have these three phrases in my mind: Stabbing the keyboard, poking the keyboard and hitting the keyboard. Are they correct or does it sound odd?

Answer (score 1):

Yes, those sound odd. They'd be something you would do when you're angry, frustrated, or both.

A neutral alternative would be "typing on the keyboard", or even "using the keyboard" (what else are you going to use the keyboard for?)